# Is it possible to achieve forwarding reference like behaviour without type deduction?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Recently I learned about universal (or forwarding) references. They work only with type deduction like in templates or with `auto` / `decltype`.

When I use an lvalue-reference (&), I can't bind it to rvalue (temporary) objects. When I use an rvalue-reference (&&), I can't bind it to lvalue object. Forwarding references can work both with non-const lvalues and rvalues.

Is it possible to achieve forwarding reference behaviour without type deduction?

```
void Foo(string && s); // rvalue-reference
void Bar(const string & s); // const lvalue-reference
void Baz(auto && s); // forwarding reference

string s = "lvalue string";

Foo(s);      // error: cannot bind lvalue to &&
Foo("test"); // OK

// works, but can't take non-const value
Bar(s);
Bar("test");

// works
Baz(s);
Baz("test");
```

Comment: `const &` was how it was done before `&&` existed.

Comment: You can always limit the type using SFINAE.

Comment: `When I use lvalue-reference (&), I can't bind it to non-const object.` Of course you can bind an lvalue-reference to a non-const object. Perhaps you meant that a non-const reference cannot bind to to a const object? Or that non-const reference cannot bind to an rvalue (like a temporary)?

Comment: @Rakete1111 thanks, didn't know about this thing

Comment: The real crux of the problem is how to handle the arguments(?) The language-lawyer stuff aside, I think life becomes simpler if you flip the problem around and look at it in-terms of what you are going to do with that argument in the function. If you need to copy it, always accept by value then move, else take it by const reference. Then it doesn't really matter what you send to it - it's frankly speaking - irrelevant.

Comment: It is not possible, and there is a reason behind it (the function would handle different types differently). Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Nim There are cases where we don't know in advance, whether we _need to copy/move the function parameter_. An example would be a function that returns a value from some cache map, where we don't know if the corresponding key is or isn't in the cache. If not, we need to copy/move the key, otherwise there is no such need. Pass by value would be therefore inefficient. Perfect forwarding would be better, but it hinders, e.g., implicit conversion to key parameter type (string literal to `std::string` etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of.  You can type-erase the concept of forward reference to a `T`.

```
template<class T>
struct forward_ref {
  using extract_sig = T(void*);
  using get_sig = T const&(void*);

  extract_sig* extract = nullptr;
  get_sig* gettor = nullptr;

  void* pvoid;


  template<class U>
  void wrap( U&& t ) {
    auto* pt = std::addressof(t);
    using pT = decltype(pt);
    pvoid = const_cast<void*>(static_cast<void const*>(pt));
    gettor = [](void* pvoid)->T const& {
      // std::cout << "getting:\n";
      auto* pt = static_cast<pT>(pvoid);
      return *pt;
    };
    extract = [](void* pvoid)->T {
      // std::cout << "extracting via " << (std::is_rvalue_reference<U&&>::value?"move":"copy") << "\n";
      auto* pt = static_cast<pT>(pvoid);
      return std::forward<U>(*pt);
    };
  }

  forward_ref(T const& t){ wrap(t); }
  forward_ref(T && t = {}){ wrap(std::move(t)); }


  bool valid() const { return gettor&&extract; }
  operator T()&&{
    // std::cout << "operator T&&\n";
    T r = extract(pvoid);
    // std::cout << "extracted\n";
    gettor=nullptr; extract=nullptr; pvoid=nullptr;
    return r;
  }
  operator T const&() const &{
    // std::cout << "operator T const&\n";
    return gettor(pvoid);
  }
  T get()&& { return std::move(*this); }
  T const& get() const& { return *this; }
};
```

So you can do this:

```
void Foo(forward_ref<std::string> s); // rvalue-reference
```

and `s` behaves (somewhat) like a forwarding reference to a `std::string`.

If you `std::move` from `s`, it either copies the incoming `std::string` or moves from it depending on if it was a rvalue or lvalue.

Now, this is pretty silly, because

```
void Foo(std::string s)
```

is going to be almost aways a better idea than that fancy `forward_ref` above.

If move is cheap and you plan on stprimg a copy, taking by value is almost as fast as forwarding reference.

If move is no cheaper than copy, just take by `const&`.

It is extremely rare that move is expensive and copy is way more expensive.

Forwarding references are useful because in generic code you do not know if move is cheap.  With a concrete type you know.

In any case, a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/245bc56e2d5d9805) of that type erased forward ref.